# Add color between navbar and banner(Front end)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

I'm a little new to front end. I'm trying to do psd to code for a project. But I have difficulty to understand. I have eagerness to learn. I use bootstrap 4. There is a whiteness between banner and navbar. There is also greenery under the banner. I know, I have many mistakes. I got help from the sample theme. Can you help me for this project?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" style="max-width: 170px; margin-top: -7px;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#feature">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#organisations">Organisations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal">Sign in</a></li>
      <li class="btn-trial"><a href="#footer">Free Trail</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <div class="banner">
<div class="bg-color">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="banner-text text-center">
        <div class="text-border">
          <h1 class="text-dec">PARAN PUL OLMASIN</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="intro-para text-center quote">
          <h2 class="big-text">ARSAM OLSUN</h2>
          <div>
            <form class="mc-trial row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class=" controls">
                  <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- End email input -->
              <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <div class=" controls">
                  <input name="EMAIL" placeholder="GSM" class="form-control" type="number">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- End email input -->
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                <p>
                  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-submit">
                  Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#feature" class="mouse-hover">
          <div class="mouse"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er5eK.jpg)

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an aside between nav and banner in HTML code, then in CSS

```
aside {
  background-color: youchoose;
}
```